# City Level Component Restriction in Google Places API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building a locality search functionality to show localities from a specific city. User will filter contents on a city page.

For this I am using Google Maps JavaScript API

This API has component restriction at Country level.

```
var options = {
types: ['(regions)'],
componentRestrictions: {country: 'in'}};
```

Now in this case, since I already know the city, I want to get the locality results for that particular city onyl.

Is there any filter for the same in this API>

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no components filter for city in Places API.

You can see a feature request in the public issue tracker for this. Have a look at [ticket 4433](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4433) and star it to add your vote.

As a workaround you can try to use city boundaries and strictBounds property of autocomplete:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteOptions

Answer (score 0):

Well I did managed to achieve it in the following way.

I filtered out the results which didn't contain the selected city

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function() {
    $('.pac-container div').each(function() {
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(cityName.toLowerCase()) == "-1") {
            $(this).hide();
        } 
    });
});
```

So out of the results for a country I filtered out those which didn't match the `cityName`